# multithreading with loops inside the run() method

Tags: java, multithreading, loops

I have the following code to test multithreading. Inside the run() method, I have a loop. I instantiate my Runnable class and pass the object thus created to two different threads. My question is- How does the JVM deal with loop indexes ? Since a single Runnable object is passed to two different threads, won't it create confusion with loop indexes ?

```
public class ThreadTest1 implements Runnable{

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ThreadTest1 tt = new ThreadTest1();
        Thread t1 = new Thread(tt);
        Thread t2 = new Thread(tt);
        t1.start();
        t2.start();
    }

    private synchronized void b() {
        try {
            for(int ii = 0; ii < 2; ii++) {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
                System.out.println("inside method 'b': " + this.toString() + "  " + Thread.currentThread());
            }
        } 
        catch (InterruptedException e) {e.printStackTrace();}
    }

    @Override
        public void run() {
        this.b();
    }
}
```

Comment: No. `ii` is a local variable. Local variables only exist within a single thread. Each thread has its own `ii`.

Comment: Two separate loops with their own indices are created; one for each thread. The threads don't share the same call to `run`.

Comment: Bingo! I understand now.

Comment: @Carcigenicate, "Two separate loops..." not a clear way of thinking about it. There is only _one_ for loop. The loop is code, and code is immutable, read-only.  Furthermore, there is only one instance of the class to which the loop belongs. What there are two of is, there are two different _threads_ executing the code. Each thread has its own call stack, and when the code tells a thread to create space for a method argument or a local variable, the thread creates that space on its own, private stack---where it is inaccessible to other threads.

Comment: P.S., It would be different if `ii` was a member variable.  In that case, there would be only one copy of it, shared by the two threads, because a member variable is stored in an object instance, and the program creates only one instance of the `ThreadTest1` class.